# Walk through Shadow and Light DOM recursively

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I am trying to walk through the shadow *and* light DOM recursively (looking for the first `input`, wherever it may be). This didn't seem to be such a hard task, so I wrote the following code

```
recursiveWalk: function(node, func) {
    var done = func(node);
    if(done){
        return true;
    }

    if('root' in node){
        this.recursiveWalk(node.root, func);
        if(done){
            return true;
        }
    }

    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        var done = this.recursiveWalk(node, func);
        if(done){
            return true;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

which ends up in an infinite loop for reasons I can't seem to figure out (my guess it has to do with the fact that elements that are in the light DOM can again be found in the shadow DOM, but elements in the shadow DOM need not be in the light DOM, but not every element has a shadow DOM... so I am stuck).

Comment: return true at the end of the function, cause there is the case that done will never be true

Comment: and why did you use node.firstChild and than node.nextSibling? do you will iterate over the childs or the siblings?

Comment: @jan: That would cause it to finish the entire function as soon as it does a recursive walk on the shadow, it should only `return true` when func returns `true` or return nothing when the walk found nothing.

Comment: @jan: `firstChild` goes down one level, and then `nextSibling` continues exploring that level, going down on every element through `this.recursiveWalk`...

Comment: ok, you lost some siblings at the beginning when you start with the first child, better you start with the first sibling and use the first child in  `this.recursiveWalk(node.firstChild, func)`, but thats not the reason for the infinit loop.

Comment: can you add your code to jsfiddle?

Comment: @jan: I want to start with a parent and then search it's entire DOM, so starting with the first child makes a lot of sense. But here's a JSFiddle as well... http://jsfiddle.net/za1gn0pe/3/

Comment: mhh, there is no infinit loop, I tested it in chrome and firefox?

Comment: @jan: Ah, sorry for the late reply, I don't care much about the infinite loop I am seeing locally (when I have an iron-form as well), it's more about the fact that it doens't work in the first place ;-) (it never lists `INPUT` whilst there definitely is an input there)

Comment: Ok, it was hard to find, your first problem is that the shadowDom is not ready, so when you iterate through it there is no shadowDom. The second problem is that the property is called shadowRoot not root. I fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/za1gn0pe/5/ (the setTimeout is only for testing, there is probably a onready event in polymer which you can use).

Comment: @jan: That's... weird :/ Because I definitely seeing stuff in `.root` locally, but go you, please do post that as an answer though so that you can score some points ;-) . And hopefully it will be useful to others as well :))

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to wait that polymer is ready:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    recursiveWalk(document.body, function (node) {
        console.log(node.nodeName);
    });
})
```

and to use the shadowDom property:

```
if ('shadowRoot' in node &&  node.shadowRoot) {
    var done = recursiveWalk(node.shadowRoot, func);
    if (done) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/za1gn0pe/7/