# Plain Javascript code that does what querySelector() and querySelectorAll() does, include shadowroots

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to write a method that takes in two params: one of the parentNode of the current element where many childNodes with shadowroots within it, the second param being the id of an element within one of the shadowroots of one of the childNodes of this parentNode param. I tried to use the generic querySelector() methods that JS come with to find the element using the id alone, but it wouldn't work due to my element tags being inside the shadowroot. Due to this reason, I had write code that are more or less hard-coded that traverse through the DOM tree by their tag name, hence the idea of writing a more dynamic method that handles the matching. Here is an html sample of what I am dealing with, using a bunch of customized web components tags (Hence why the shadowroots):

```
<body>
<my-app>
    <main id="main">
        <my-app-pub>
            <section>
                <my-app-workpackage id="wp">
                    <my-table id="mytable1" data={...}>
                        #shadow-root (open)
                            <style></style>
                            <table>
                                <thead></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id="tr1"></tr>
                                    <tr id="tr2"></tr>
                                    <tr id="tr3"></tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </my-table>

                    <my-table id="mytable2" data={...}>
                        #shadow-root (open)
                            <style></style>
                            <table>
                                <thead></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id="tr4"></tr>
                                    <tr id="tr5"></tr>
                                    <tr id="tr6"></tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </my-table>
                </my-app-workpackage>
            </section>
        </my-app-pub>
    </main>
</my-app>
```

Giving that I have a variable with the parent element `<my-app-workpackage>`, and the id of the element I want to find as `tr2`, how should I write a method to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a parser that will check recursively the DOM :

For each node :

1. If there's a Shadow DOM (`shadowRoot` not `null`), parse the Shadow tree.
2. Or else parse the children DOM tree.

If you use `<slot>` you'll have look for distributed nodes too, but it's not asked in your question...

Comment: Thank you, I believe if there is a shadow DOM, the parser will need to check BOTH the normal DOM tree and Shadow tree. Can you explain the part with the `<slot>` tag in regarding to distributed nodes please?

Comment: It depends on what you try to select. Since the normal ("light") DOM tree is masked by the Shadow DOM, maybe you won't want to select its content. About <slot>: they can reveal some part of the light DOM that are then called "distributed" nodes. So you might want to parse them too, and in the  order they appear sequentially.

Comment: What is the shadow root under a node that has a `<slot>` tag that leads to entire `div`? As far as I see if the entire `div` is under the `<slot>` tag, it is now considered part of the light dom of the parent, and should be able to parse normally as any other dom nodes, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a particular case

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780562/walk-through-shadow-and-light-dom-recursively