# How can I traverse the DOM picking nodes that are slotted in the correct position

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-element

I am making a "psuedo", "super" form like custom-element.  I want to traverse the nodes in order looking for nodes that match a particular criteria (one is that they have a method `function` called `validate`, the other is that they have the properties `name` and `value`).  In my traversal I want to

- Avoid child nodes of an element which have transferred to slots within an elements shadowroot.
- Traverse the shadow root on an element and in that traversal pick up elements that have been transferred to the slots within it.
- Not traverse the children or the shadow root of elements that match the criteria I mention above.

It seems that there are two possible approaches.

1. Create a "treewalker" and use that to iterate through the nodes it finds.
2. Simply use the Node API with such calls as `Node.hasChildNodes()` and `Node.childNodes`

However, I can find no documentation on either of these two possibilities that explains what happens to slotted content.  The documentation on these typically ignores any mention of slots and slotted content - probably because they were written before slots became part of the spec.

There is obviously `Slot.assignedNodes()` method which I could use to find whats in a slot as I am traversing the shadowRoot (although even the documentation of that is ambiguous in what the optional `flatten` value does - it says it returns default content when set to true, but does it return default content if there is no actual slots provided when the value is set to false? - and why is it called "flatten" anyway, doesn't seem appropriate for what it does?).  But if I am using that, I also need a way to avoid the nodes which have been moved to these slots when traversing the children

So how is the best way of forming the actions described above can someone give me some clues?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53182226/4600982

Comment: @Supersharp Problem with that question and your answer is that it doesn't really include slots and my question is all about slots

Comment: It's a general answer with a clus for <slot> (that corresponds to you "treewalker" solution). About 'flatten': it returns default content *only* if 'true'. Maybe you should provide some code example if you want a specific answer because there are very differents use cases with different optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the best way of doing this was manually.  The crux of the test is that `node.assignedSlot` is not null when an element is assigned to a slot, so can use this when scanning children to ignore children when they are assigned to a slot (and to include them when scanning `slot.assignedNodes()`

Here is a module with a `walk` default function to walk the element provided. `criteria` is a callback function per node which the caller can use to check if the node meets the criteria looked for (see question) and therefore not scan the children.

```
function _walk(node,criteria, slot) {
  if (node.assignedSlot === null || node.assignedSlot === slot) {
    if (node.localName === 'slot') {
      const assignedNodes = node.assignedNodes();
      if (assignedNodes.length  === 0) {
        _walkA(node.children, criteria);
      } else {
        _walkA(assignedNodes.filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE), criteria, node);
      }
    } else if (!criteria(node)) {
      if (customElements.get(node.localName)) _walkA(node.shadowRoot.children,criteria);
      _walkA(node.children, criteria);
    }
  }
}
function _walkA(nodes,criteria, slot) {
  for (let n of nodes) {
    _walk(n,criteria, slot);
  }
}
export default function walk(walknode, criteria) {
  _walk(walknode,criteria,null);
}
```