# Is there a way to find all shadowDOMs present in a document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-component, shadow-dom

I am writing a small library that attaches a handler to nodeInserted event on document.The document may contain one or more shadowDOMs deep down inside. The event  does not work inside shodowDOMs.

I need to explicitly attach event handler to all shadowDOMs. Is there a way I could find all shadowDOMs in the document so that I can traverse through them and attach events explictly?

Comment: Can you not conclude on the existence of shadow DOMs based on actual HTML elements (any special attributes etc.) - in which case you can pre-select your Html elements with shadow DOMs and then manipulate them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Walk through Shadow and Light DOM recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780562/walk-through-shadow-and-light-dom-recursively)

Comment: @user1514042 no, as i wrote, I am writing an opensource library.

Comment: @BilalAlam fair enough, not every shadowdom would allow for its modification, which you probably know. I'd still try comming up with an empirical way of defining your shadow dom'ed elements. out of interest what are you trying to achieve by adding extra event handles (if it's not passwords mining of course)?